# Elastic alert format list of items

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have a list of items retrieved from my query using aggregations.  I want to print this list of items in my email with each appearing on a separate line.  Right now I can print everything but it all appears one after the other i.e. `file1.txt file2.txt`.  I would like for it to appear like

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Below is the action to create the email.

```
"actions": {
    "email_users": {
        "email": {
            "profile": "standard",
            "to": [
                "jcarpenter@mydomain.com"
            ],
            "subject": "File Identifier",
            "body": {
                "html": "<p>Files could not be identified due bad receiver id.  There were {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} files that could not be identified.</p> <ul><li>{{#ctx.payload.aggregations.file_name.buckets}}{{key}}{{/ctx.payload.aggregations.file_name.buckets}}</li></ul>"
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I print the items this way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to format the items using the following command.

```
"actions": {
"email_users": {
  "email": {
    "profile": "standard",
    "to": [
      "jcarpenter@mydomain.com"
    ],
    "subject": "File Identifier",
    "body": {
      "html": "<p>Files could not be identified due bad receiver id.  There were {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} files that could not be identified.</p> <div><ul>{{#ctx.payload.aggregations.file_name.buckets}}{{#key}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/key}}{{/ctx.payload.aggregations.file_name.buckets}}</ul></div><p>These files have been sent to quarantine.</p>"
    }
  }
}
```